# Is file sharing and printers a "kill switch"?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer, network-shares

[image]

### The Settings menu for media and the public folders ask separately if I want to share them. Are those settings superior to  "file sharing and printers"?

For example if I deactivate "file sharing and printers" but in the media sharing have the setting to share media, then everyone at work can see my pictures?

Or if I have public folder sharing on yes but "file sharing and printers" set to no, Can then somebody see the public folder or no?

Thank you!

Comment: Media sharing uses the MTP protocols which are very different from standard Netbios file sharing, so while both will "share" your images, they are differant in terms of the devices and protocols they support. So Yes, disable them both individually. Not sure about public sharing though. I believe that still uses netbios so I'd be suprised if you could run public sharing without having F&P enabled as well.

Comment: Hi Frank! So from your answer i take that netbios (what was already yesterday mentioned) is the standard way of sharing files. From what i read in the internet MTP sounds like its for transferring music, pictures or videos to my cellphone or a media advice. I mean if i connect to a network of my company and not a professional hacker is trying to hack me, and i have media sharing on on but file sharing off, then  a normal person can not see my pictures or?

Comment: yes they can, if they use an OS like Win7 or newer, which supports MTP protocols by default, and the organization does not disable them by policy (and since you have to configure your network yourself, this is unlikely). Windows uses MTP for windows media player, and some network neighbourhood features, so folks will see your device in My Computer -> Network and in WMP. Disable it unless you want to share it.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for that answer that helped! It seems that i can not upvote your comments do i need a certain number of credits or somethign?